# How do I connect Spark to JDBC driver in Zeppelin?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to pull in data from a SQL server to a Hive table using Spark in a Zeppelin notebook.

I am trying to run the following code:

```
%pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName('sample') \
.getOrCreate()

#set url, table, etc.

df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
.option('url', url) \
.option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver') \
.option('dbtable', table) \
.option('user', user) \
.option('password', password) \
.load()
```

However, I keep getting the exception:

```
...
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
...
```

I have been trying to figure this out all day and I believe something is wrong with how I am trying to set up the driver. I have a driver under `/tmp/sqljdbc42.jar` on the instance. Can you please explain how I can let Spark know where this driver is? I have tried many different ways both through the shell and through the interpreter editor.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I also should note that I loaded the jar to my instance throug Zeppelin's shell (%sh) using

```
curl -o /tmp/sqljdbc42.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/6.4.0.jre8/mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar
pyspark --driver-class-path /tmp/sqljdbc42.jar --jars /tmp/sqljdbc42.jar
```

Comment: Try SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS environment variable in conf/zeppelin-env.sh
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS = " --jar /jdbc/jar/file.jar"

Comment: I think you mean  export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS =" --jars /jdbc/jar/file.jar". And I tried running that through Zeppelin (%sh) and it did not work. I think it has more to do with the driver-class-path.

Comment: any answer on this? after doing everything specified https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/jdbc.html#redshift I'm still getting "No suitable driver" error

Comment: See the answer I just posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this:

1. `scp` driver jar onto the cluster driver node
2. Go to Zeppelin interpreter and scroll to the Spark section then click edit.
3. Write the complete path to the jar under artifacts e.g. `/home/Hadoop/mssql-jdbc.jar` and nothing else.
4. Click save.

Then you should be good!

Answer (score 0):

You can add it through Web UI in Interpreter settings as follow:

- Click Interpreter in menu
- Click 'edit' button in the Spark interpreter
- Add the path for the jar in the artifact field
- Then just save and restart interpreter.

Comment: For some reason the error changed to a NullPointerException when I did this.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Tomas, you can add the driver (or any library) using maven in the interpreter:

- Click Interpreter in menu
- Click 'edit' button in the Spark interpreter
- Add the path for the jar in the artifact field
- Add the groupId:artifactId:version

For example, in your case, you can use `com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:8.4.1.jre8` in artifact field.

When you restart the interpreter, it will download and add the dependency for you.